# CABasicAnimation not working in iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cabasicanimation, caanimation

I just want to animate a view's background color. What I did up to now is:

```
CABasicAnimation *backgroundColorAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"backgroundColor"];
backgroundColorAnimation.duration = 1.0;
backgroundColorAnimation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 0.5;
backgroundColorAnimation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
backgroundColorAnimation.autoreverses = YES;
backgroundColorAnimation.fromValue = (id)[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
backgroundColorAnimation.toValue = (id)[[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
[self.layer addAnimation:backgroundColorAnimation forKey:@"animation.backgroundColor"];
```

The above works fine up to iOS 8 but not with iOS 9. Any help with what has changed?

Comment: How does the code 'not work with iOS 9'?